# Compute of metric and curvature under transformation of coordinates.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Let $\widehat{g}_{ij}(x,t)$ 
be a solution of $$\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial t}=-2R_{ij},$$
 and $\varphi_t:M\rightarrow M$
is a family of diffeomorphisms of $M$.
Let $$g_{ij}(x,t)=\varphi_t^*\widehat{g}_{ij}(x,t)$$ 
be the pull-back metric and 
$y(x,t)=\varphi_t(x)=\{y^1(x,t),...,y^n(x,t)\}$,$\partial_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\partial_t=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}.$

How to show that:

1,   $g_{ij}(x,t)=\partial_iy^a\partial_jy^b\widehat{g}_{ab}(y,t)$

2,   $\partial_t \widehat{g}_{ab}(y,t)=-2\widehat{R}_{ab}(y,t)+
\frac{\partial\widehat{y}_{ab}}{\partial y^r}\frac{\partial y^r}{\partial t}$