# Compute of exchange of covariant derivatives.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $v=v_kdx^k$,$R_{ijkl}=g_{kp}R^p_{ijl}$,How to show that :

$$
\nabla_i\nabla_jv_k-\nabla_j\nabla_iv_k=R_{ijkl}g^{lm}v_m
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Using the defintion of $R$, write $R_{ijk}^l$ in terms of $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ and its derivatives. Then your formula can be proved by direct computation, using

$$\nabla_i v_j = \partial_iv_j - \Gamma_{ij}^k v_k.$$

Comment: Thanks , but I compute it in the all morning ,and got nothing . I will try it in other time . Do you have idea about  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481512/symbol-of-operator-and-eigenvectors-of-symbol

Comment: and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481642/compute-of-metric-and-curvature-under-transformation-of-coordinates